# How to print '*' without spaces?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How can i print '*' without spaces? Here is simple ruby on rails code. And it prints it with spaces like in image: 
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXxLZ.png)

```
<% 5.times do %>
  <%= "*" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do use [String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-2A) method.

```
<%= "*" * 5 %>
```

Note: If you write the code in one line `<% 5.times do %><%= "*" %><% end %>`, it also prints `*` without in between spaces.